# Cycle's image sequence texture not playing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image

[image: compared even and cycle view port]I have an image sequence texture that plays fine in eevee but when I switch to cycles it no longer plays. This happens in a new scene as well.

Has anyone seen something like this? I have heard of a animate checkbox in the image texture node but I can not find anything like this in my 2.83 version.

The last thing I did was update my RTX drivers and render settings.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue by **upgrading to Blender 2.9** as it recently came out.

I am still not sure exactly what caused the problem in the first place but I made sure to **reset my settings and preferences over from scratch** and I now have full image sequence functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a node setup I just made in Blender 2.83.4, it plays both Eevee and Cycles for me:

[image]

Comment: hmm, I really appreciate your response! If this setup is working for you then I must have a more complicated issue happening.. not sure where to start

Comment: click "cyclic."

Comment: Unfortunately with cyclic checked it stayed the same.